# Attendance system in mysql

Tags: mysql, view, pivot

I have these three tables:

Students table:

```
id | name
1  | Charles
2  | Peter
3  | Mary
4  | John
5  | Mike
...
```

Week table:

```
id | week | year
1  | 1    | 2012
2  | 3    | 2012
3  | 6    | 2012
4  | 8    | 2012
5  | 9    | 2012
6  | 12   | 2012
...
```

Attendance table:

```
id | student | week | control
1  | 1       | 1    | P (present)
1  | 2       | 1    | A (absent)
1  | 1       | 3    | P
1  | 2       | 3    | A
1  | 3       | 9    | P
```

What I need is a Pivot view like this, but I have no idea how to get such structure in MySQL:

```
id | student | week-1 | week-3 | week-9
1  | Charles | P      | P      | A
2  | Peter   | A      | A      | P
3  | Mary    | P      | A      | P
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not have a pivot function but you can replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.  Your code will be similar to the following:

```
select s.id,
  s.name,
  max(case when week=1 then control else 'A' end) Week1,
  max(case when week=3 then control else 'A' end) Week3,
  max(case when week=9 then control else 'A' end) Week9
from students s
inner join attendance a
  on s.id = a.student
group by s.id, s.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d264f0/5)

If you have an unknown number of `week` values that you want to return, then you will need to use dynamic SQL in a prepared statement.  The code will be:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN week = ',
      week,
      ' THEN control else ''A'' END) AS week',
      week
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM weeks;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT s.id,
              s.name, ', @sql, ' 
            from students s
            inner join attendance a
              on s.id = a.student
            group by s.id, s.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d264f0/7)

The result will be:

```
| ID |    NAME | WEEK1 | WEEK3 | WEEK6 | WEEK8 | WEEK9 | WEEK12 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Charles |     P |     P |     A |     A |     A |      A |
|  2 |   Peter |     A |     A |     A |     A |     A |      A |
|  3 |    Mary |     A |     A |     A |     A |     P |      A |
```

Note: If you want to return all `Students` in the table regardless of whether or not they have a matching row in the `attendance` table, then you should use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select s.id,
  s.name,
  max(case when week=1 then control else 'A' end) Week1,
  max(case when week=3 then control else 'A' end) Week3,
  max(case when week=9 then control else 'A' end) Week9
from students s
left join attendance a
  on s.id = a.student
group by s.id, s.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d264f0/8).

Comment: Bluefeet, thanks for answer. It solved my problem.
For any reason I can't use Dynamic SQL in my server. I've tried trough HeidiSQL and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Vanderlei I am not sure why you cannot use dynamic SQL, do you get an error?

Comment: I tried to create a view trough this code, but phpMyAdmin does't allow it.

Comment: @Vanderlei Dynamic SQL needs to be in a procedure

Comment: #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Comment: The last version, Bluefeet

Comment: @Vanderlei Are you able to get it to work in a procedure?

Comment: Yes, I'm. It works as procedure.